# Understanding function space associated with vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

In a vector space, pick a vector $v=(v(1), v(2),...).$

In function space, pick a function $f=2x$ in which $f=\{f(r)\}_{r\in R},\,f$ is considered as a point in function space as the case in vector space.

Then, can I visualize in my mind that $v(1)$ corresponds to $f(1),\, v(2)$ corresponds to $f(2),\, v(2)$ corresponds to $f(2),...$ and so on in an imaginary infinite dimensional coordinate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 'standard' vector spaces are **ALL!!!** a function spaces. Note that it is **BY DEFINITION!!!**: $\mathbb{R}^N\equiv\{v:\{1,\ldots, N\}\to\mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: Sorry if it seems I'm getting little upset about it.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether it is reasonable to correspond two elements. That is, each value of function is put on its own dimension which leads infinite dimensional vector space. Is it correct?

Comment: You mean like an infinite product of one dimensional spaces?

Comment: Yes, it might be my way of catching it.

Comment: No problem, then think about: What is the (cartesian) product $\mathbb{C}^3$ of one-dimensional spaces $\mathbb{C}$? Sloppy answer: It is triples $\{(x,y,z):x,y,z\in\mathbb{C}\}$. Correct answer: It is already functions $\{f:\{1,2,3\}\to\mathbb{C}:f(1),f(2),f(3)\in\mathbb{C}\}$. Now think about: What is the infinite (cartesian) product $\prod_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ of one-dimensional spaces $\mathbb{C}$? Finally think about: What is $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$? Answer: It is a certain subspace of $\prod_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks! you still remember me :). I absolutely agree with that.

Comment: Yes I remember you ;) Still in Munich?